# Best way to handle data in Azure vmss

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I am using Azure vmss for auto scaling. I will deploy one API in the vmss which will upload a file and save it in a disk.
We need some recommendation regarding data storage.Below is our understanding:
-When we add managed disk with vmss , each VM get the same size disk which should be mounted. Ex.: if we add 50 GB disk to a vmss, each vm will get 50 GB unmounted disk.
-we will save file in vm's disk and later on if the particular vm gets de-allocated because of auto scaling . will we loose the data from vm's disk?
If yes then what is the best approach to retain the data.
If no how we can retrieve the file from the de-allocated vm?

Comment: I should be able to download the files

Comment: Also asked here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cbaa508-c85c-4dff-8a09-8152ce9d4ff7/best-way-to-handle-data-in-azure-vmss?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the answer provided in the [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cbaa508-c85c-4dff-8a09-8152ce9d4ff7/best-way-to-handle-data-in-azure-vmss?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) by my teammate for broader audience.

Since your use case required saving and retrieving files, You can provision a Azure File share and you can mount it to the VM using a custom script extension.

Instead of using the keys for connecting to the storage account from the VM, we can also assign a managed service identity to the VM.

By this approach same file share will be mounted to all the VM's in the VMSS. All VMS can write and read from the file share at a time.